# My code won't do the sum; only the elements of the matrix appear and then nothing happens

Tags: c#

```
namespace Suma_diagonala_secundara
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n, i, j, s = 0;
            Console.Write("n= ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int[,] tab = new int[n, n];

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("tab[{0}][{1}]= ", i + 1, j + 1);
                    tab[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            Console.Write("\nElementele matricii sunt: ");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    Console.Write("{0} ", tab[i, j]);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Suma elementelor de pe diagonala secundara este: ");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {                
                s = s + tab[i, n - i + 1];

            }                                                                                
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rebecca, could you please provide more information.  Based on the code and your question, you want to sum but you do not see the sum.  You only receive the position of the array.  Is that correct?  Could you provide a background and what the intent of your code is.

Comment: what I intent to do is the sum of the elements on the secondary diagonal

Comment: Okay, I will analyze again and provide a solution.

Comment: It's good that you've added code, but questions without any body-text are rarely answerable. Would you edit this to add an introduction?

Answer (score 2):

In your loop

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{                
    s = s + tab[i, n - i + 1];
}
```

you are accessing the array out of bounds, since `n - 0 + 1 = n + 1` is larger than `n - 1` (the largest index in `tab`).

What you actually want is (note the parentheses)

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{                
    s = s + tab[i, n - (i + 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
s = s + tab[i, n - i + 1];
```

Is throwing an IndexOutOfRangeException because you are requesting an index higher than the array capacity.

The correct loop code is (with decrement instead increment)

```
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     s = s + tab[i, n - i - 1];
 }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i modified the code to something like this: for(i=0;i<n;i++){ if(j==n-i-1){ s=s+tab[i,j]} } and it worked.